# How to make a popup window with tab in Android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to make a popup window with some tabs at top/bottom position in Android? I tried to search for it, but have nothing so far. 
What I want is, when I clicked the tab, then the content of the popupwindow will change. The real example is like the emoticon popup in BeeTalk. 
Please kindly help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to inflate the dialog with your own custom layout, which will include everything the dialog needs to have.

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_custom_dialog, null )
```

Note that this will override the default layout so you'll need to specify everything in the dialog.

Comment: Thanks..But can you show me how to make tab in the popup window? and also how to implement the tab click listener.